# I want to shade first quadrant of the ellipse please guide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shading

Please find below the ellipse code, I want to shade the first quadrant of the ellipse, please guide how can I do that. Thanks in advance .

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (-5,0)--(5,0) (4.1,0)node{A} (0,3)--(0,-3)(0,2.2)node{B};
\draw(0,0)node{O}circle[x radius = 4 cm , y radius = 2 cm]; 

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[red] (4,0) arc[x radius = 4 cm , y radius = 2 cm,start angle=0,end
 angle=90] |- cycle;
 \draw (-5,0)--(5,0) (4.1,0)node{A} (0,3)--(0,-3)(0,2.2)node{B};
 \draw(0,0)node{O}circle[x radius = 4 cm , y radius = 2 cm]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to put the nodes on top of the axes, consider using `contour`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[red] (4,0) arc[x radius = 4 cm , y radius = 2 cm,start angle=0,end
 angle=90] |- cycle;
 \draw (-5,0)--(5,0) (4,0)node[right]{\contour{white}{$A$}} 
  (0,3)--(0,-3) (0,2)node[above]{\contour{white}{$B$}};
 \draw(0,0)node{\contour{white}{$O$}} 
 circle[x radius = 4 cm , y radius = 2 cm]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am really greatful to you, it is really great... thanks a ton... God bless you .... thanks once again..